# issue with auto increment field

Tags: python, mysql, database

```
def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
   conn = mysql.connector.connect(
   user="root", 
   password = "heer0304", 
   host="localhost", 
   database = "Python_book"
   )
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()

insert("C++","Balaguruswami",2007,5454132548)

print(view())
```

Here first book_id value is auto_increment and primary key so hear i dont need to pass book_id value. so when i try this error occurs and the error is below

```
 File "e:/python/app5_Database_App_Tkinter/backend.py", line 42, in <module>
    insert("C++","Balaguruswami",2007,5454132548)
  File "e:/python/app5_Database_App_Tkinter/backend.py", line 23, in insert
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 560, in execute
    raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Help in this to run code

Comment: Try using `%s` instead of `?`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding column names to be on safer side

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO book(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
```

Comment: Try this
`cur.execute("INSERT INTO book(col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES ({},{},{},{})".format(title,author,year,isbn))`